# Automatically upload file

Tags: windows, open-source, monitoring, uploader

I'm looking for a (open source) software program that can upload CSV files to a server.

A third party software application is generating CSV files with measurements information. When a new file is created or an existing file has changed, it should be automatically uploaded to our server.

The recommended software should have:

- Directory/file watching that triggers an event
- Upload of the file to a server
- Confirmation that the upload is finished
- Logging information about upload status and errors

I know that it isn't realy difficult to write this software, but at this time we have no intrest in writing it.

Comment: You could use `robocopy` within Windows, or DSynchronize; both will do what you want (do not want to flush this out as an answer, feel free to if you like it).

Answer (score 2):

[Syncfusion Data Integration Platform](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/data-integration) is an option to consider. The Data Integration Platform is based on [Apache Nifi](https://nifi.apache.org/), so you could also consider Nifi if you need it to be open source. The Syncfusion Data Integration platform has additional usability enhancements and support included.

You need to host Syncfusion Data Integration server/Nifi on some server (cloud/on premise).

These processors are available for the scenario you have described and scheduling is built into the system.

- Directory/file watching that triggers an event: [GetFile](https://help.syncfusion.com/data-integration/processors/getfile) processor to read the files in directory
- Upload of the file to a server: Yes. Can be done using FTP or any other uplooad interface. [PutFTP](https://help.syncfusion.com/data-integration/processors/putftp) [Sample link](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/UploadFileAutomatically-1267370069)
- Confirmation that the upload is finished: File upload data flow can be monitored and notification can be through Email (using PutEmail), Microsoft Teams (using [PutMicrosoftTeams](https://help.syncfusion.com/data-integration/processors/putmicrosofteams)) or Slack Messenger (using [PutSlack](https://help.syncfusion.com/data-integration/processors/putslack))
- Logging information about upload status and errors: Errors can be logged to file and also published to the bulletin.

[image: File upload integration using Syncfusion Data Integration platform]

The Data Integration Platform available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue) and flat licensing is available even otherwise.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.